# Eclipse: How to commit file to SVN repository on each save using Remote System Explorer

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, remote-server, subversive

I work in Eclipse on PHP project with Remote System Explorer plugin. RSE upload my file on each save to the server. Can I also commit that file on each save automatically using Subversive to the SVN repository?

Comment: Why do you need to commit it on each save operation? Even when you changed just one character and saved the file you want to commit this to SVN repo? What's the task exactly?

Comment: Of course no, but I don't know how to commit repo within use RSE, so in general my goal is to commit files from Eclipse within use RSE